# Summing discrete 3d coordinate lengths

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, summation, permutations, arithmetic

Consider a three dimensional discrete coordinate system $(x,y,z)$, where $x,y,z\in$ natural numbers.

The number of digits describing an integer coordinate for each dimension is  $l_c=\lfloor log(c) \rfloor+1$, where $c$ is $x$, $y$ or $z$.

The total number of digits describing a point in the space is $l=\lfloor log(x) \rfloor+\lfloor log(y) \rfloor+\lfloor log(z) \rfloor+3$.

I am looking for a formula to describe how many points each total coordinate digit length can describe.

Any suggestions?

**Example:**

As one digit for each dimension can describe a total of $(10)(10)(10)$ points, the total coordinate length $3$ can describe a total of $10^3$ points in the space.

Two digits for any of the dimensions and one digit for the rest gives a total number of points possible to describe as $(3)(10^2-10)(10)(10)$. In other words, a total of four digits can describe a maximum of $27000$ points in the space.

A total of five coordinate digits can describe a maximum of $$(3)(10^3-10^2)(10)(10)+(3)(10^2-10)^2(10)=513000$$ points in the space.

Six digits can describe a total number of $$(3)(10^4-10^3)(10)(10)+(6)(10^3-10^2)(10^2-10)(10)+(10^2-10)^3=8289000$$ points in the space.

And so on.

Any suggestions on how to produce a formula are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OPs approach is fine and in fact the examples already present all possible different variants  of the  number  of  digits $k_1,k_2,k_3$ of the three  dimensions  with $k_1+k_2+k_3=n$ digits.

- All three dimensions are equal:   $\qquad\qquad\  k_1=k_2=k_3$
- Two are equal, the third is different: $\qquad\  k_1=k_2, k_1\ne k_3$
- All three are pairwise different: $\qquad\qquad\; k_1\ne k_2, k_1\ne k_3, k_2\ne  k_3$

As there are some different cases to distinguish we conveniently use *[Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)*.

> Let $n\ge 3$. We start with
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{{1\leq  k_1\leq k_2\leq  k_3\leq  n}\atop{k_1+k_2+k_3=n}}
> &\left\{\left(10^{k_1}-10^{k_1-1}[[k_1>1]]\right)^3[[k_1=k_2=k_3]]\right.\tag{1}\\
> &\qquad+3\left(10^{k_1}-10^{k_1-1}[[k_1>1]]\right)^2\left(10^{k_3}-10^{k_3-1}[[k_3>1]]\right)\\
> &\qquad\qquad\cdot[[k_1=k_2,k_1\ne k_3]]\\
> &\qquad+3\left(10^{k_1}-10^{k_1-1}[[k_1>1]]\right)\left(10^{k_3}-10^{k_3-1}[[k_3>1]]\right)^2\tag{2}\\
> &\qquad\qquad\cdot[[k_1\ne k_2,k_2= k_3]]\\
> &\qquad\left.+6\prod_{j=1}^3\left(10^{k_j}-10^{k_j-1}[[k_j>1]]\right)[[k_1\ne k_2,k_1\ne k_3,k_2\ne  k_3]]\right\}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

We can simplify the three summands (1), (2) and (3) somewhat.

> **Case 1:** All three dimensions are equal
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{{1\leq  k_1\leq k_2\leq  k_3\leq  n}\atop{k_1+k_2+k_3=n}}&\left(10^{k_1}-10^{k_1-1}[[k_1>1]]\right)^3[[k_1=k_2=k_3]]\\
> &=\sum_{{1\leq  k_1= k_2= k_3\leq  n}\atop{k_1+k_2+k_3=n}}\left(10^{k_1}-10^{k_1-1}[[k_1>1]]\right)^3\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\left(10^{\frac{n}{3}}-10^{\frac{n}{3}-1}[[n>3]]\right)^3[[3|n]]}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

Since $k_1=k_2=k_3$ we have only one case to consider, namely $3k_1=n$ resp. $k_1=\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor$. This implies that $n$ has to be a multiple of $3$ which is asserted by $[[3|n]]$, otherwise the sum is zero.

> **Case 2:** Two are equal, the third is different
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> &3\sum_{{1\leq  k_1\leq k_2\leq  k_3\leq  n}\atop{k_1+k_2+k_3=n}}
> \left(10^{k_1}-10^{k_1-1}[[k_1>1]]\right)^2\left(10^{k_3}-10^{k_3-1}[[k_3>1]]\right)\\
> &\qquad\qquad\cdot[[k_1=k_2,k_1\ne k_3]]\\
> &\qquad+3\sum_{{1\leq  k_1\leq k_2\leq  k_3\leq  n}\atop{k_1+k_2+k_3=n}}
> \left(10^{k_1}-10^{k_1-1}[[k_1>1]]\right)\left(10^{k_3}-10^{k_3-1}[[k_3>1]]\right)^2\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\cdot[[k_1\ne k_2,k_2= k_3]]\\
> &\quad=3\sum_{{1\leq  k_1= k_2<  k_3\leq  n}\atop{2k_1+k_3=n}}
> \left(10^{k_1}-10^{k_1-1}[[k_1>1]]\right)^2\left(10^{k_3}-10^{k_3-1}[[k_3>1]]\right)\\
> &\qquad+3\sum_{{1\leq  k_1< k_2= k_3\leq  n}\atop{k_1+2k_3=n}}
> \left(10^{k_1}-10^{k_1-1}[[k_1>1]]\right)\left(10^{k_3}-10^{k_3-1}[[k_3>1]]\right)^2\\
> &\quad\,\,\color{blue}{=3\sum_{k_1=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{3}\right\rfloor}
> \left(10^{k_1}-10^{k_1-1}[[k_1>1]]\right)^2\left(10^{n-2k_1}-10^{n-2k_1-1}\right)}\\
> &\qquad\,\,\color{blue}{+3\sum_{k_3=\left\lceil\frac{n+1}{3}\right\rceil}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor}
> \left(10^{n-2k_3}-10^{n-2k_3-1}[[n-2k_3>1]]\right)\left(10^{k_3}-10^{k_3-1}\right)^2}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}

The upper limit  $\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{3}\right\rfloor$ of the left-hand sum in (5)  follows from the index region
\begin{align*}
&1\leq k_1=k_2<k_3\leq n\\
&2k_1+k_3=n\qquad\qquad\qquad\to\qquad k_3=n-2k_1>k_1\qquad\to\qquad k_1<\frac{n}{3}\\
\end{align*}

The lower limit  $\left\lceil\frac{n+1}{3}\right\rceil$ of the right-hand sum in (5)  follows from the index region
\begin{align*}
&1\leq k_1<k_2=k_3\leq n\\
&k_1+2k_3=n\qquad\qquad\qquad\to\qquad k_1=n-2k_3<k_3\qquad\to\qquad k_3>\frac{n}{3}\\
\end{align*}

The upper limit  $\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor$ of the right-hand sum in (5)  follows from the index region
\begin{align*}
&1\leq k_1<k_2=k_3\leq n\\
&k_1+2k_3=n\qquad\qquad\qquad\to\qquad n-2k_3\geq 1\qquad\to\qquad k_3\leq \frac{n-1}{2}\\
\end{align*}

> **Case 3:** All three are pairwise different
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> &6\sum_{{1\leq  k_1\leq k_2\leq  k_3\leq  n}\atop{k_1+k_2+k_3=n}}
> \prod_{j=1}^3\left(10^{k_j}-10^{k_j-1}[[k_j>1]]\right)[[k_1\ne k_2,k_1\ne k_3,k_2\ne  k_3]]\\
> &\qquad=6\sum_{{1\leq  k_1< k_2< k_3\leq  n}\atop{k_1+k_2+k_3=n}}
> \prod_{j=1}^3\left(10^{k_j}-10^{k_j-1}[[k_j>1]]\right)\\
> &\qquad\,\,\color{blue}{=6\sum_{k_1=1}^{n-2}\sum_{k_2=k_1+1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-k_1-1}{2}\right\rfloor}\left(10^{k_1}-10^{k_1-1}[[k_1>1]]\right)\left(10^{k_2}-10^{k_2-1}\right)}\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\color{blue}{\cdot\left(10^{n-k_1-k_2}-10^{n-k_1-k_2-1}\right)}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}
>
> Putting (4) - (6) together gives a simplified formula of (1) - (3).

The upper limit  $\left\lfloor\frac{n-k_1-1}{2}\right\rfloor$ of the sum in (6)  follows from the index region
\begin{align*}
&1\leq  k_1< k_2< k_3\leq  n\\
&k_1+k_2+k_3=n\qquad\qquad\to\qquad k_3=n-k_1-k_2>k_2\qquad\to\qquad k_2<\frac{n-k_1}{2}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Very nice answer. Many thanks. However, when entering (6) for n=6 into WolframAlpha ([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6*sum%5B+%2810%5Ea-10%5E%28a-1%29*Boole%5Ba%3E1%5D%29*%2810%5Eb-10%5E%28b-1%29%29*%2810%5E%286-a-b%29-10%5E%286-a-b-1%29*Boole%5B%286-a-b%29%3E1%5D%29+%2C%7Ba%2C1%2C6-2%7D%2C%7Bb%2Ca%2B1%2C6-1%7D%5D)) it gives a funny answer (49680000). Do you think there might be a way to express the sums without Iverson brackets? Kind regards

Comment: @ijaubgiaugf:  You're welcome.  Thanks for pointing at the mistake. I've revised and corrected the answer accordingly. A nice aspect is  the number of Iverson brackets could be reduced. In order to completely avoid the Iverson brackets we would have to write the different cases $k_1=1$ and $k_1>1$ separately.

Comment: Ok! I see. Many thanks for having a second look. I tried it out and it doesn't seem to quite add up in my calculations. For example, it seems that in the case of n=7, (5) misses the case of (3)(10)(10^3-10^2)^2.

Comment: @ijaubgiaugf: Fixed and hopefully corrected. Review is welcome.

Comment: It works perfectly. Many thanks for your very nice answer!

Comment: @ijaubgiaugf: You're welcome. Good to see that it works fine now. :-)

Comment: I have a another question if you don't mind: do you think it is difficult to produce a corresponding formula for 4 dimensions, or even for an arbitrary number of dimensions?

Comment: @ijaubgiaugf:  I don't think that it is difficult. But it is presumably somewhat more cumbersome to derive a formula.

Comment: Many thanks, I see!